# Pull-to-refresh on deleted question throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When viewing a question and it's deleted, pulling down to refresh will crash the app.

Here is the logcat log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13354): java.lang.RuntimeException: [v0.1.58] java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.question.QuestionTask.getByQuestionId(QuestionTask.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.question.QuestionTask.getByQuestionId(QuestionTask.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.QuestionFragment.refresh(QuestionFragment.java:142)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.QuestionFragment.onRefresh(QuestionFragment.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.callRefreshListener(PullToRefreshBase.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.access$000(PullToRefreshBase.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase$1.onSmoothScrollFinished(PullToRefreshBase.java:742)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase$SmoothScrollRunnable.run(PullToRefreshBase.java:1638)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.question.QuestionTask.getByQuestionId(QuestionTask.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    ... 20 more
```

**Steps to reproduce:**
Monitor MSO for programming questions, when one appears view it with the Android app and wait for it to be deleted. Then pull to refresh.

Comment: +1 for the steps to reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.60 coming out later tonight. The app will now show you an error message rather than crashing.